# Rails 3 Gemfile Gems not Loading After Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, redcarpet

I'm writing an application in Rails 3 with Ruby v2.0.0.

I have a helper in app/helpers/posts_helper.rb:

```
module PostsHelper
  def markdown(text)
    @redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, {fenced_code_blocks: true}) unless @redcarpet
    @redcarpet.render text
  end
end
```

My `Gemfile` contains `gem 'redcarpet', '~> 2.2'` and I have run `bundle install` with success. However, I get this error whenever I try to load a page that uses this helper:

```
uninitialized constant PostsHelper::Redcarpet
```

What can I do to get this working? I'm baffled at this problem.

Edit:

I've also tested Redcarpet in `rails console`:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML).render('text *markdownified*')
=> "<p>text <em>markdownified</em></p>\n"
```

So it works in the console, just not in my helper (or controller, I've tried that, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is trying to find Redcarpet in the PostsHelper namespace.  Use `::Redcarpet` to raise that to the global namespace

Comment: I've changed the two references from `Redcarpet` to `::Redcarpet` and now I'm getting this: `uninitialized constant Redcarpet`.

Comment: What happens if you execute that `@redcarpet = ...` statement in the Rails console?  It works for me.

Comment: 1) Did you restart rails server after installing redcarpet? 2) Try it without instance variables, no @. 3) add require to helper, shouldnt be needed?

Comment: I can't believe it. I didn't restart the server. Wow. Thank you for your wonderful common sense!